# How to post a new context to my wit bot?

Tags: laravel, guzzle, wit.ai

I'm writing a bot using Wit.ai and I'm having trouble understanding context. More specifically how/when to set it. As I've understood it you set the context by posting to the API at any point in time you see fit, for example when executing a function defined in a wit story. At least that's the approach I'm aiming for with the code below. Sadly it generates an error though so I wonder, am I trying to set the context in an incorrect way or is there something wrong with my Guzzle post?

```
    private function storeUserName($entities) {
      $witcall = $this->wit->post($this->wit_base_url.'/converse', 
        [
            'form_params' => [
                'username' => $entities->contact[0]->value
            ],
            'query' => [
                'v' => '1',
                'session_id' => 'vk-'.$this->thread_id
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.env('WIT_TOKEN', false)
            ]
        ]
    );

    return [
        'msg' => 'nice',
        'type' => 'msg'
    ];
}
```

My error:

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 111:
Client error: `POST https://api.wit.ai/converse?v=1&session_id=vk-1` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
Unable to parse context in body
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out using `form_params` was incorrect, changed to `json` and now it works fine. Like this:

```
$call = $this->wit->request('POST', 'converse', [
        'json' => $this->context, 
        'query' => [
            'v' => '1',
            'session_id' => 'vk-'.$this->thread_id
        ]
    ]);
```